# SQL Server - Error 8623 Severity 16 State 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, optimization

Fist of all, let me clarify that I'm brand new to this whole DBA world so I apologize in advance.

One of the databases I'm (since a couple of days ago) in charge of is throwing an Error 8623: "*The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.*"

This particular instance is running SQL Server 2014 SP2.

How do I find which query is causing this? I've been having a hard time finding documentation on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Extended Events to capture failing queries.
Here is a link to a detailed howto article.
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/what-queries-are-failing-in-my-sql-server/

TSQL to create xevents and start:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION what_queries_are_failing
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported
(
ACTION (sqlserver.sql_text, sqlserver.tsql_stack, sqlserver.database_id, sqlserver.username)
WHERE ([severity]> 15)
)
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
(set filename = 'C:\XEventSessions\what_queries_are_failing.xel' ,
metadatafile = 'C:\XEventSessions\what_queries_are_failing.xem',
max_file_size = 5,
max_rollover_files = 5)
WITH (MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 5SECONDS)
GO

-- Start the session
ALTER EVENT SESSION what_queries_are_failing
ON SERVER STATE = START
GO

-- Trigger Level 16 error
select * from Person.Person where ModifiedDate='20aaa'; 

--Query the logfile
;with events_cte as(
select
DATEADD(mi,DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
xevents.event_data.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')) AS [err_timestamp],
xevents.event_data.value('(event/data[@name="severity"]/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS [err_severity],
xevents.event_data.value('(event/data[@name="error_number"]/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS [err_number],
xevents.event_data.value('(event/data[@name="message"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(512)') AS [err_message],
xevents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [sql_text],
xevents.event_data
from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file
('C:\XEventSessions\what_queries_are_failing*.xel',
'C:\XEventSessions\what_queries_are_failing*.xem',null, null)
cross apply (select CAST(event_data as XML) as event_data) as xevents
)
SELECT *
from events_cte
order by err_timestamp;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get parameters from query in sql_text?